# How to interact to Hbase via knox using Python?

Tags: python, hbase, apache-knox

I'm trying to interact with hbase throght knox using Python, In python 
The admin give a list of knox API endpoints for hive, hbase and spark like:
`https://knox-devl.www.mysite.com:9042/gateway/MYSITEHDO/hbaseversion/cluster`

Now, since I'm using Python's happybase library, my connection code is

```
import happybase

connection=happybase.Connection('https://knox-devl.www.mysite.com/gateway/MYSITEHDO/hbaseversion/cluster',port=9042)
connection.open()
print(connection.tables())
```

The error it show is:
`thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(message="Could not connect to ('https://knox-devl.www.mysite.com/gateway/MYSITEHDO/hbaseversion/cluster', 9042)", type=1)`

Also I tried with Phoenixdb lib

```
import phoenixdb

database_url = 'https://knox-devl.www.mysite.com:9042/gateway/MYSITEHDO/hbaseversion/cluster'
conn = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW tables")
```

But I'm getting another error: 
`phoenixdb.errors.InterfaceError: ('RPC request failed', None, None, BadStatusLine("''",))
Exception phoenixdb.errors.InterfaceError: InterfaceError('RPC request failed', None, None, BadStatusLine("''",)) in <bound method Connection.__del__ of <phoenixdb.connection.Connection object at 0x10bc97d90>> ignored`

The only way I can get some of the data through curl:

```
curl -i -k -u guest:guest-password 'https://knox-devl.www.mysite.com:9042/gateway/MYSITEHDO/hbaseversion/cluster'
```

But there is no SQL commands there.

did anyone know how to do this or there something I'm missing here, like ask for a different URL or enable something on the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you identified, the only way to talk to HBase through Knox is via HBase's REST API. Happybase is trying to connect directly to HBase via RPC, which Knox will block.

You can't use Happybase from outside a cluster with Knox enabled.

A good tutorial for using the HBase REST API with Python can be found [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-use-the-apache-hbase-rest-interface-part-1/). In case the link ever dies, some of the most useful commands from this article are:

- Look at a table's schema:

  ```
  request = requests.get(baseurl + "/" + tablename + "/schema")
  ```
- Insert a row:

  ```
  cellset = Element('CellSet')

  linenumber = 0;

  for line in shakespeare:      
      rowKey = username + "-" + filename + "-" + str(linenumber).zfill(6)
      rowKeyEncoded = base64.b64encode(rowKey)

      row = SubElement(cellset, 'Row', key=rowKeyEncoded)

      messageencoded = base64.b64encode(line.strip())
      linenumberencoded = encode(linenumber)
      usernameencoded = base64.b64encode(username)

      # Add bleet cell
      cell = SubElement(row, 'Cell', column=messagecolumnencoded)
      cell.text = messageencoded

      # Add username cell
      cell = SubElement(row, 'Cell', column=usernamecolumnencoded)
      cell.text = usernameencoded

      # Add Line Number cell
      cell = SubElement(row, 'Cell', column=linenumbercolumnencoded)
      cell.text = linenumberencoded

      linenumber = linenumber + 1

      # Submit XML to REST server
      request = requests.post(baseurl + "/" + tablename + "/fakerow", data=tostring(cellset), headers={"Content-Type" : "text/xml", "Accept" : "text/xml"})
  ```
- Delete a table:

  ```
  request = requests.delete(baseurl + "/" + tablename + "/schema")
  ```

Comment: So is there a way to allow the RPC protocol in knox, or should I limited to work with the RESP API? btw that was a great answer.

Comment: The function of Knox is to act as a gateway to your cluster, ensuring external access is restricted to REST requests through a single URL and port. I'm afraid RPC won't work. The Java HBase API has the ability to work via REST, but it doesn't look like there's anything similar for Happybase. You could ask the developers https://github.com/wbolster/happybase